# Line is not drawn in Kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.graphics import Line


class Draw(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Draw, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Widget has a property called canvas
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 1, 0, .5, mode='rgba')
            Line(points=(350, 400, 500, 800, 650, 400, 300, 650, 700, 650, 350, 400), width=3)

            Color(0, 0, 1, .5, mode='rgba')
            Line(bezier=(200, 100, 250, 150, 300, 50, 350, 100), width=3)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

[The result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2mVg.png)

Both the green line and the blue line should show up, but only the green line shows up
The Green line shows a star
The Blue line shows a wave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### self.pos

If you resize the application from your code, you should notice that sometimes the **blue** line is plotted. This is because you did not bind the *position* of the widget with the canvas drawing (Line, Rectangle, etc...)

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.graphics import Line


class Draw(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Draw, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.update_canvas()

    def update_canvas(self, *args):
        # Widget has a property called canvas
        with self.canvas:
            # add self.pos to the line position
            Color(0, 1, 0, .5, mode='rgba')
            Line(pos=self.pos, points=(350, 400, 500, 800, 650, 400, 300, 650, 700, 650, 350, 400), width=3)

            Color(0, 0, 1, .5, mode='rgba')
            Line(pos=self.pos, bezier=(200, 100, 250, 150, 300, 50, 350, 100), width=3)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

However, I noticed that sometimes the blue line is not visible depending on the OpenGL Context initialization.
The issue is, in general, caused by **alpha** channel of the color.

> ... if the current color has an alpha less than 1.0, a stencil will be used internally to draw the line.

This internal stencil has not a stable behavior.

Source: [Kivy.Lines](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.html?highlight=line#kivy.graphics.Line)

Comment: Thank you very much. But what will happen if I add pos=self.pos?

Comment: It should bind the line drawing position with the *widget position*